# ruby gem module-wide variable in separate file

Tags: ruby

I have a Gem I am trying to write where I have multiple files defining the classes for my module.  The structure looks like this:

```
/root_path
 |- lib/
 |  |- my_module/
 |     |- lib/
 |        |- some_class.rb
 |        |- another_class.rb
 |- my_module.rb
```

In the `/root_path/my_module.rb` file I have this defined:

```
module MyModule
  class << self
    attr_accessor :something
  end
  self.something = 'xyz'
end
```

In the `/root_path/lib/my_module/lib/some_class.rb` file, I want to print what is in the module's `something` variable like this:

```
module MyModule
  class SomeClass
    class << self

      def do_stuff
        puts MyModule.something
      end

    end
  end
end
```

When I run my spec test, though, I get the following message:

> undefined method `something' for MyModule:Module

What am I doing wrong here?

### Update 1

I added `require ./lib/my_module` and changed the module code to:

```
module MyModule
  @@something

  def something
    @@something
  end
  def something=(something)
    @@something = something
  end
end
```

While that works, it just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have forgotten to `require 'my_module'` in `lib/my_module/lib/some_class.rb`.

Comment: Even if I add the full path to the file, I still get the same error.  The interpreter doesn't complain about the require, I just get the "undefined method" error again.

Comment: I lied.  I must have had a typo somewhere... it's working now.